# How to do Oracle date ranking?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I have a table about members subscriptions which has four main columns  :

```
1-member_id 
2-subscription_no 
3-subscription_start_date 
4-subscription_end_Date
```

And every member(has an unique member id) may have more than one subscription so I need to get the latest subscription date for every member .

Now my scenario is like this:

I need to get the members who did not subscribed again after 5 months of the his active subscription during 2012.

I.e I need to know the members who the company has lost them as subscribers as the criteria of being lost is not subscribe after 5 months of the end of his last active subscription during 2012.

Comment: So, they're lost if they subscribed again after six months?

Comment: thanks guys for these answers but non of them do the requested i think i didnot make my self clear enough.

Comment: our company delivering service with different subscriptions periods from one month to one year ,so i need to know the churn subscripers who had a subscription active in 2012 and after this subscription ended  didn`t renew again in 5 months period.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following select.

```
select member_id, max(subscription_end_Date)
from yourTable
where subscription_end_Date>= trunc(trunc(sysdate,'year')-1,'year')
group by member_id having months_between(sysdate,max(subscription_end_Date))>=5;
```

where the `trunc(trunc(sysdate,'year')-1,'year')`  returns the first day of last year.

By using the trunc condition, the query selects only the members that have at least one subscription with subscription_end_Date > '01 - JAN - 2012' and by using the `months_between(sysdate,max(subscription_end_Date))>=5` it returns only those that have not subscribed for at least 5 months from last subscription_end_Date.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests depending on your schenario as bellow

```
 create table table1 (id integer, nm integer, stdate date, endate date);
```

inserted some test data

```
Insert into TABLE1(ID, NM, STDATE, ENDATE)
 Values (1, 2, TO_DATE('04/09/2013 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('06/17/2013 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into TABLE1(ID, NM, STDATE, ENDATE)
 Values(1, 1, TO_DATE('03/25/2013 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('06/14/2013 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into TABLE1(ID, NM, STDATE, ENDATE)
 Values(2, 3, TO_DATE('03/05/2013 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('06/15/2013 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into TABLE1(ID, NM, STDATE, ENDATE)
 Values(2, 2, TO_DATE('03/06/2013 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('06/28/2013 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
COMMIT;
```

And the query is

```
with q1 as (
  select id, nm, stdate, endate,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by endate desc) as rn 
  from table1
) select * from q1 where rn=1
and <last5 months criteria using endate>;
```

result of the query

```
select id, nm, stdate, endate,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by endate desc) as rn 
  from table1
```

will give the following result, then you can filter the result using the rn column and last 5 months criteria.

```
id  nm  sdate       endate      rn
1   2   09.04.2013  17.06.2013  1
1   1   25.03.2013  14.06.2013  2
2   2   06.03.2013  28.06.2013  1
2   3   05.03.2013  15.06.2013  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
select old.member_id
from subscription old left join subscription renew on old.member_id = renew.member_id
and renew.start_date <= old.end_date + 165 -- (roughly 5 months)
where old.end_date >= {d '2012-01-01'} 
and old.end_date < {d '2013-01-01'}
and renew.start_date is null
```

oracle might not like that date format, but this should be the correct logic.

Comment: Instead of *roughly 5 months*, you could use  `renew.start_date <= add_months(old.end_date,5)`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do your job [Assuming that query will be executed now as 5 months have passed this year], whole logic is that max subscription end date lies in 2012:

```
select member_id from (
select member_id, max(subscription_end_Date) ed, max(subscription_start_Date) sd
  from yourTable
group by member_id) a
where trunc(ed, 'YEAR') = 2012 and sd <= add_months(ed,5)
```